# How can the random forest algorithm deal with the fact of not having strictly independent observations?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I have a data set with calls from two species of birds of the same genus. For each species there are 10 subjects and different numbers of calls for each (range of 1-8 calls per subject).
Measurements of peak frequency, duration, bandwidth, etc. were made for each call.

Species A (calls=48; subjects=10)
Species B (calls=37; subjects=10)
Predictor variables (n=9)

I think I could classify the calls using random forest and thus know which variables are most important to classify both species. But I wonder: if subject 1 of species A has 3 calls, and subject 2 has 5 calls. Am I in a pseudoreplication situation?

How can the random forest algorithm deal with the fact of not having strictly independent observations because they are different call's from the same subject?

Comment: You seem to be asserting that it can. Perhaps it can't. The important thing is how you intend to use it. If your inference is going to look like your training dataset, it should work, otherwise it may not. Kind of applies to all algorithms, including regression. You can do regression on non-independent measurements. What you get out of it however is probably going to be very different to what you would get with independent measurements.